# Find the highest combination of values in column 1 based on max value in column 2

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with 3 columns(in reality of ~2000 rows). I want to return the values of column A which has the highest maximum total score in column B, with the restriction of a max value in column C. For example:

```
colName    col1  col2
John     7      50
Jim      3      25
James    2      25
Peter    9      110
Robert   1      75
Hank     1      75
```

Let's say the max total/sum value of col2 is 100. The highest combination of combined  values in col1 would be 7+3+2=12.
I would like to return the list of names that would be returned:
John, Jim, James

Q1: How would I do this?

Q2: Alternatively, It would be interesting to return the entire rows of the dataframe with the values of the highest possible combination in a dataframe:

```
 colName    col1  col2
    John     7      50
    Jim      3      25
    James    2      25
```

Comment: Do you want to keep it in order?

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is a [*0/1 knapsack problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem).  The [`adagio`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adagio/index.html) package implements a knapsack solver in R.

```
> tbl
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  colName  col1  col2
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 John        7    50
2 Jim         3    25
3 James       2    25
4 Peter       9   110
5 Robert      1    75
6 Hank        1    75
> tbl <- tbl[tbl$col2 <= 100, ]  # `adagio` will complain otherwise
> soln <- knapsack(tbl$col2, tbl$col1, 100)
> tbl[soln$indices, ]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  colName  col1  col2
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 John        7    50
2 Jim         3    25
3 James       2    25
```

Comment: This is great! Never heard of that package. Will have to take a closer look. What if I would also like to include a maximum number of rows as part of the formula? ie. only a maximum of 3 rows can be part of the result?

Comment: @Martijn Once you know the name of the problem it turns out this has been asked and answered multiple times. You should do a search of the 31 questions and answers that come up in a search for `"[r] knapsack"`.

Comment: @d125q You're right, I should've been looking into the solution myself. I have read the documentation of adagio, but it doesn't seem to mention adding a restricted n to the function. I have found alternatives that come close [mpSolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980658/knapsack-algorithm-restricted-to-n-element-solution) and [GA](http://www.dataminingapps.com/2017/03/solving-the-knapsack-problem-with-a-simple-genetic-algorithm/). There is even another question that is similar to mine here, but with no responses. If you could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.